# Generating a repeating sequence an increasingly truncated number of times in R

Tags: r, sequence

Consider some vector in R: `x`

```
x<-1:10
```

I'd like to create a repeating sequence of `x`, with the first element of each sequence truncated with each repetition, yielding the same output as would be given by issuing the following command in R:

```
c(1:10,2:10,3:10,4:10,5:10,6:10,7:10,8:10,9:10,10:10)
```

Can this be done?  In reality, I'm working with a much larger vector for `x`.  I'm playing with numerous combinations of the `rep()` function, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of a hack, because you can decompose what you are trying to do into two sequences:

```
rep(0:9, 10:1) + sequence(10:1)
```

You can see what each part does. I don't know if there is a way to feed the parameters to `rep()` or `seq()` like you would do in a Python expansion.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an alternative using `mapply`:

```
unlist(mapply(":", 1:10, 10))
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  3  4  5  6  7
# [25]  8  9 10  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  5  6  7  8  9 10  6  7  8  9 10  7  8  9
# [49] 10  8  9 10  9 10 10
```

Comment: this is 27 chars, the accepted answer is 28, mine (comment above) is 30.  Code golf time?

Answer (score 1):

```
unlist(sapply(1:10, function(x) { x:10 }))
```

Comment: or `unlist(sapply(1:10, seq, to=10))` (more compact but maybe a little bit more obscure ... so this more explicit version may be better)